# Want to use this but giving error in syntax help me to fix permanent in Query Builder Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
SELECT installation 
FROM `id` 
WHERE `outlet_id` = '9' 
AND `status` = '1' 
GROUP BY `page_rank` `asc` 
ORDER BY `page_rank=0` 
LIMIT -1, 1
```

Page Rank=0 gives error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`asc` ORDER BY `page_rank=0` LIMIT -1, 1' at line 5

Comment: use `... order by page_rank limit ...`

Comment: you can't use `asc` with group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query using codeigniter query builder class -

```
$this->db->select('installation') // column name
$this->db->from('id'); // table name
$this->db->where('outlet_id', 9); // condition
$this->db->where('status', 1);
$this->db->group_by('page_rank');
$this->db->order_by('page_rank', 'ASC');
$this->db->limit(1, 0); // will show 1 result starting from 0 ie first result
$query = $this->db->get()->result();

return $query;
```

**Produces**

> ```
> SELECT installation 
> FROM `id` 
> WHERE `outlet_id` = 9
> AND `status` = 1 
> GROUP BY `page_rank` 
> ORDER BY `page_rank` ASC 
> LIMIT 0, 1
> ```

See if it solves your issue.